# Build a string for a search query

Tags: c#, sql

I am building a string for a search query and I think I am doing it the wrong way.

So basically I have serveral textfields, dates, integers and so on in one form. On submit I am checking the forms if its empty or not and building the query string.

I am submitting the model and building a kind of "pyramid" by checking if it is null or not, which is ending in a very large if statement (marked emphasis).

```
public string CreateSearchQuery(SearchViewModel model)
    {
        StringBuilder buildQueryString = new StringBuilder(2048);

        if (model == null)
        {
            //empty model: return newest results
            return buildQueryString.Append("SELECT * FROM newTbl.files").ToString();
        }

        buildQueryString.Append("SELECT * FROM newTbl.files INNER JOIN newTbl.folders ON folders.id = f_folders_id WHERE ");

        if (model.NumberClubs > 0)
        {
            buildQueryString.Append("folders.numberClubs = ");
            buildQueryString.Append(model.NumberClubs);
        }

        if(model.MrDateFrom != null)
        {
             //those if statements will get very large, when I have more then ten fields
            *if (model.NumberClubs > 0)*
            {
                buildQueryString.Append(" AND ");
            }
            buildQueryString.Append("folders.mrDate = '");
            buildQueryString.Append(model.MrDateFrom.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            buildQueryString.Append("'");
        }

        if (model.Period > 0)
        {
            //those if statements will get very large, when I have more then ten fields
            *if (model.NumberClubs > 0 || model.MrDateFrom != null)*
            {
                buildQueryString.Append(" AND ");
            }
            buildQueryString.Append("folders.period = ");
            buildQueryString.Append(model.Period);
        }

        buildQueryString.Append(" ORDER BY newTbl.period DESC");

        return buildQueryString.ToString();
    }
```

I don't think that this is the correct way. So I have a model with several values, but to build a query string I have to check if it is empty or not to append the `AND`? I mean it is working, but it is really complicated (in my opinion).

Comment: Is there any particular reason your are not using [`SqlParameter`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: @t3chb0t Yes, our aim is first use stringbuilder, then use NpgsqlParameter (Postgres) and after that we should use Dapper. To see the different things (pros & cons - so also SQL Injection) and how it is working.

Answer (score 2):

As t3chb0t suggested, when creating SQL based on user input use **ALWAYS** SqlParameters to prevent sql injection!

Instead of creating SQL using a StringBuilder, I would try to abstract common structures and create classes to represent them. That makes the code more readable and maintainable.

A more structured solution could look like that:

```
    private class Condition
    {
        public Condition(string field, string parameterName, object paramerterValue)
        {
            this.Field = field;
            this.ParameterName = parameterName;
            this.ParameterValue = paramerterValue;
        }

        public string Field { get; }
        public string ParameterName { get; }
        public object ParameterValue { get; }

        public override string ToString() => $"{Field} = @{ParameterValue}";
    }

    public class SqlQuery
    {
        public SqlQuery(string sql, SqlParameter[] parameters = null)
        {
            this.Sql = sql;
            this.SqlParameters = parameters ?? new SqlParameter[0];
        }

        public string Sql { get; }
        public SqlParameter[] SqlParameters { get; }
    }

    public SqlQuery CreateSearchQuery(SearchViewModel model)
    {
        if (model == null) return new SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM newTbl.files");

        var sql = "SELECT * FROM newTbl.files fi INNER JOIN newTbl.folders fo ON fo.id = fi.f_folders_id";

        var conditions = new List<Condition>();
        var sqlParameters = new SqlParameter[0];
        var pcount = 1;

        if (model.NumberClubs > 0) conditions.Add(new Condition("fo.numberClubs", $"p{pcount++}", model.NumberClubs));
        if (model.MrDateFrom != null) conditions.Add(new Condition("fo.mrDate", $"p{pcount++}", model.MrDateFrom.Value));
        if (model.Period > 0) conditions.Add(new Condition("fo.period", $"p{pcount++}", model.Period));

        if (conditions.Count > 0)
        {
            var whereClause = " WHERE " + string.Join(" AND ", conditions);
            sqlParameters = conditions.Select(c => new SlqParameter(c.ParameterName, c.ParameterValue)).ToArray();
            sql += whereClause;
        }

        sql += " ORDER BY newTbl.period DESC";

        return new SqlQuery(sql, sqlParameters);
    }
```

Comment: I answered techbot. ;) Yes, there is a reason, to see how the stuff is working/changing. So my question was about the if clauses. What is `$"p{pcount++}"`. I am new to C#, but I don't know this syntax. If I am right, it should be the parameterName? Yes, it is easier to read, but when I have 10+ textfields, i will came up with +10 if statements? Is that ok or bad?